# Clean URLs Test Fails with Drupal 7 on EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 Instance

Tags: apache, drupal, amazon-ec2

I've already enabled mod-rewrite with

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I've added my Drupal7 install to the apache config file located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (note: Is this the correct config file to edit?)

```
<Directory "/var/www/myDrupal">
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I restarted Apache2 with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Yet it still fails the Clean URL test in Drupal. I've been banging my head against the keyboard for far too long. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: me answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759103/the-clean-url-test-failed-in-drupal-7/19852719#19852719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .htaccess looks good, and the apache config file is set correctly with AllowOverride All, try navigating to clean-urls configuration page by yourSite.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls and enable it! Clean URL's test sometimes fails even though your server is properly configured to rewrite.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have it residing in a "myDrupal" folder off the root, then it is in a sub directory. You need to edit .htaccess, and uncomment "RewriteBase /" on line 110.

Just change

```
# RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase
```

Then Flush your Drupal Cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: this was exactly the point on _Ubuntu 13.10 Server 64bit_ after I've installed **drupal7** package and enabled the _mod-rewrite_ on Apache2.

This must be flagged as the correct answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod_rewrite. You'll have to cause the following to happen during instance createion:

## a2enmod rewrite

## service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Enabling clean urls for **Ubuntu 14.04**

(1) Run the command **a2enmod rewrite** on your ubuntu (Command Line Interface) CLI  to make sure rewrites are installed.

(2) vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

a.  Under all the  **AllowOverride All**

(3) In the **.htaccess file** under /var/www/ if that is your place of drupal installation make sure the **Rewritebase /** is uncommented and correct. If your drupal installation is **Rewritebase /var/www/drupa**l, then change it to that.

(4) Run command **service apache2 restart** on your ubuntu CLI and you should be good.
* Optional - make sure your root

~Good Luck